# Taking a text file of strings and turning it into an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, text, java.util.scanner

I have to take all of the lines in the text and turn them into an array of objects. The first line in the text says how many lines there are. I'm having problems populating the array. It won't let me use `input.nextLine` since the array is of objects not strings. This is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File members = new File ("members.csv");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (members);

    int N = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    Object[] memberArray;
    memberArray = new Object[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        memberArray = input.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(memberArray[]);
    }
```

Comment: In what language?  Is this Java or C#?  Please add the appropriate language to your question's tags.

Comment: @Paddy C# Main starts with a capital M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to index the array with `memberArray[i]` and it should work fine.

`memberArray[i] = input.nextLine();`

When you print the array out, you will probably want to use another for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < memberArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(memberArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spell out how the individual values of each line get represented in an Object.  Also, I'm pretty sure you'll need to subclass Object for the particular information you want to represent.  Since you've said nothing about that information, either in an object or in the file, that's about all the help I can give.